# NHibernate: How to return list of scalar values (from one column) using CreateSQLQuery?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

What is the best/cleanest method of calling a native SQL returning a list of scalar values (ints in my case) having ISession object?

I am trying to run the following but I am always getting some errors:

```
var query = _session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT Id FROM SomeTable");

A. var ids = query.List<int>(); // <-- throws ArgumentNullException "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: item"
B. var ids = query.List(); returns one element array with no valid information.
C. query.SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean<int>());
var ids = query.List<int>(); // throws PropertyNotFoundException: "Could not find a setter for property 'Id' in class 'System.Int32'"
```

Is there a way to retrieve a list of ints without creating an entity class containing just one int property named Id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `List` from `CreateSQLQuery` you will get a instance of `IList` and it internally it is a `List<object>`. If you have null values on this result, you will not be able to convert to `int` because it is a value type. So, a solution is to iterate over the result and convert it when it is a valid integer. For sample:

```
var values = _session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT Id FROM SomeTable").List();
var ids = new List<int>();

foreach (var item in values)
{
   if (item != null)
      ids.Add(Convert.ToInt32(item));
}
```

If this is a mapped table on the nhibernate scope, you could use LINQ to do this, for sample:

```
var ids = session.Query<SomeEntity>().Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you are not using `IQueryOver`, but it is simpler, dynamic and cleaner than the way you are doing this now.

```
public IList<TReturn> GetValues<TEntity, TReturn>(IProjection column, Junction where, int top) where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    IQueryOver<TEntity> query = null;
    if(where == null)
        query = session.QueryOver<TEntity>().Select(column);
    else
        query = session.QueryOver<TEntity>().Select(column).Where(where);

    IList<TReturn> instance = null;
    if(top == 0)
        instance = query.List<TReturn>();
    else
        instance = query.Take(top).List<TReturn>();
    return instance;
}
```

`TEntity` in above code is entity that represent (mapped to) your table. Note that this is just to build the query. It will NOT return Entity.

`TReturn` is the return type. This can be any standard data type like `int` in your case.

`IProjection column` parameter is the name of the column you want to select.

`Junction where` parameter allows you to specify the filter on rows if any. To retrieve all rows, pass it `null`.

Following is the way you call it:

```
Junction where = Restrictions.Conjunction();
where.Add(Restrictions.Eq(..........));

IList<int> idList = GetValues<SomeTableEntity, int>(Projections.Property<SomeTableEntity>(x => x.Id), where, 0);
```

This way, you avoid writing hard-coded SQL query as string in your code. As you can see, this function can be used with any Entity (table) and any column.